# mysql join where one field is a part of a field in a other table

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I'm looking for something like this:

```
SELECT german_subsidiaries.*, customers.* 
FROM german_subsidiaries INNER JOIN customers 
ON customers.name LIKE '%'+german_subsidiaries.searchable_name+'%'
```

unfortunately this doesn't work,

Any idea where I can make a like to be a part of a join statement? And to make this like operation compare two different fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)** function to merge strings in MYSQL

```
SELECT german_subsidiaries.*, customers.* 
FROM german_subsidiaries 
INNER JOIN customers ON customers.name 
LIKE CONCAT('%', german_subsidiaries.searchable_name, '%')
```